# Is it possible to upgrade Manjaro to latest stable without full installation?

Tags: manjaro

New versions are coming pretty quickly.

I have Manjaro Fluxbox 15.09 and 15.10 has just been released.

To get the new stable version can I upgrade or do I need to fully install the new version?

---

UPDATE:

In 15.09 the update process says the system is up to date.

Also,

```
sudo pacman -Syy
[sudo] password for cman: 
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core                     134.6 KiB   660K/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
 extra                   1937.6 KiB   874K/s 00:02 [######################] 100%
 community                  3.1 MiB   802K/s 00:04 [######################] 100%
 multilib                 171.7 KiB   890K/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
[cman@cipc ~]$ sudo pacman -Su
:: Starting full system upgrade...
 there is nothing to do
```

Comment: Manjaro is a derivative of Archlinux, as such it's a "rolling release" OS, meaning you don't bother with the usual 6 months upgrade blockage of Ubuntu, you're basicly always up-to-date when you install all the updates.

Comment: @cylgalad - well, although 15.10 stable has been released 2 days ago, in 15.09 the update process says the system is up to date. It may be a temporary error? I see that when I try to install 15.10, the graphical installer says "install 15.09 Bellatrix"

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Pacman_Overview#Updating_the_System), use the following commands to update:

```
sudo pacman -Syy

sudo pacman -Su
```

Comment: see update in question